# Wait for background request to finish in Alamofire and array is loaded before continuing swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I know there is another question on here just like this but it wasn't clearly answered by anyone and there was no accepted answer. I have a method loadDetail which takes a completionHandler using the UIBackgroundFetchResult. This method is called when I select a cell to load the detailed data for that cell from an array. When this method is called I want the method its called from to wait until the detailResults array is filled before continuing. How can I do this and what am I doing wrong?

```
func loadDetail(urlPath: String, completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult)     -> Void)!){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlPath)
        .responseJSON { _, _, result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let jsonObj = JSON(data)
                if let data = jsonObj["results"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                    //array is filled in the line below
                    self.detailResults = data
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            case .Failure(_, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    print("Background Fetch Complete")
}
```

Here is the collectionView method that loadDetail is called from, you can see the comment where it is called pertaining to what I would like it to do.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let data = results?[indexPath.row]
    let detailData: JSON
    var testString: String = ""
    let vc: DetailBrowseViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailBrowseViewController") as! DetailBrowseViewController

    if let titleString = data?["title"] {
        vc.titleString = titleString.stringValue
        testString = titleString.stringValue
        testString = testString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-")
        testString = testString.lowercaseString
        reusableUrl.replaceRange(Range<String.Index>(start: reusableUrl.startIndex.advancedBy(146), end: reusableUrl.startIndex.advancedBy(146)), with: testString)

        self.loadDetail(reusableUrl, completionHandler:{(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void in
            //I want this collectionView method to somehow pause and wait until the detailResults array is filled and then continue
            print("success")
        })
    }

    detailData = (detailResults?[indexPath.row])!

    if let priceString = detailResults?[indexPath.row]["price"] {
        print(detailData)
        vc.priceString = priceString.stringValue
    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

The problem is, the loadDetail method goes straight through without waiting, causing the array to be nil when its called in the collectionView method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, you need to call `completionHandler` when `self.detailResults` is populated with JSON data from response.

I will try to figure our the main idea:
 - call `competitionHandler` only when data was successfully parsed
 - move necessary code (which should wait for response) into the place where data is already loaded.

First you need to move `completionHandler` call to the end of the .Success case block. I think you don't need to move forward if response is fail.

So result will be:

```
func loadDetail(urlPath: String, completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult)     -> Void)!){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlPath)
        .responseJSON { _, _, result in
            switch result {
            case .Success(let data):
                let jsonObj = JSON(data)
                if let data = jsonObj["results"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                    //array is filled in the line below
                    self.detailResults = data
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
                }
            case .Failure(_, let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }

    print("Background Fetch Complete")
}
```

Then you need to move related code (which should wait for response) to the `completionHandler` like so:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let data = results?[indexPath.row]
    let detailData: JSON
    var testString: String = ""
    let vc: DetailBrowseViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailBrowseViewController") as! DetailBrowseViewController

    if let titleString = data?["title"] {
        vc.titleString = titleString.stringValue
        testString = titleString.stringValue
        testString = testString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-")
        testString = testString.lowercaseString
        reusableUrl.replaceRange(Range<String.Index>(start: reusableUrl.startIndex.advancedBy(146), end: reusableUrl.startIndex.advancedBy(146)), with: testString)

        self.loadDetail(reusableUrl, completionHandler:{(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void in
            //I want this collectionView method to somehow pause and wait until the detailResults array is filled and then continue
            print("success")
            detailData = (detailResults?[indexPath.row])!

            if let priceString = detailResults?[indexPath.row]["price"] {
                print(detailData)
                vc.priceString = priceString.stringValue
            }
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
```